# How to import and use static javascript object in webdriverIO testing?

Tags: javascript, selenium, automated-tests, cypress, webdriver-io

I am trying to test some values present in elements, the values are stored in a static object, this is the approach I am taking.

File - someObjects.js (stores the static objects)

```js
class SomeObjects {
    static headers = {
        header1: "Something",
        header2: "Something else",
    };
}
export default SomeObjects;
```

Now I want to check whether some element matches header1. So this is the test file that I am running

```js
import SomeObjects from "../../SomeObjects";

const HomePage = require('../../HomePage');

describe("", () => {

    it("", () => {
        HomePage.open()
        const title = browser.$('#title');
        expect(title).toHaveText(SomeObjects.headers.header1);
    });
});
```

However, this is not working out at all. Any help regarding this would be appreciated, thanks.
P.S. This is the error message I am getting on running the test.
`[0-0]  Error:  Unable to load spec files quite likely because they rely on` browser `object that is not fully initialised.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have missed **new** keyword and braces **()** while exporting class, your code should look something like this..

```
class SomeObjects {
   static headers = {
       header1: "Something",
       header2: "Something else",
    };
}
export default new SomeObjects();
```

Also this can be achieved using constants class or in using json file. Few example you will find in my personal webdriverio git repo [WDIO6_TypeScript_BDD](https://github.com/sadabnepal/WDIO6_TypeScript_BDD)

Answer (score -1):

The best Cypress way I have found is - [Fixture](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture.html#Accessing-Fixture-Data)

For your example - you can add the object in a json file - for example myFixture.json - located in fixtures folder:

```
{
    "header": {
        "header1": "Something",
        "header2": "Something else",
    };
}
```

Then in the test:

```
describe("", () => {

    it("", () => {
        HomePage.open()
        const title = browser.$('#title');
        cy.fixture('myFixture.json')
            .then(object =>{
                expect(title).toHaveText(object.headers.header1);
            })

    });
});
```

Comment: How does this help with webdriverIO testing?

Comment: I am giving answer based on cypress docs as best as I can.

Comment: I am pretty sure Syantan is looking for an webdriverIO answer not a Cypress answer, none of the code he shows seems to be Cypress.